# Create JQuery Light Box With Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I Work On Create Simple JQuery LightBox With Slide, So What is I Need That When I Click on Any Image, I Want This Image To Added to img Tag That it's Inside Div With Class .lightbox, And When Click On .next The Code Will Get The Next Image of The Current Image And When Click on previous The Code Will Get The Previous Image of The Current Image:


**Second:** I'd Like To Add Fade Effect Between Sliders.

**Note:** I'd Like To Understand More And More About JavaScript And JQuery So Please Not Suggest Any Plugin.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".image img").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".lightbox img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    });
    $(".lightbox .next").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

```css
.image{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
.image img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
.lightbox{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px auto;
    border:2px solid #0094ff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:40px;
}
.lightbox img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.lightbox div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 234, 119, 0.80);
    cursor:pointer;
} 
.lightbox .left{
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/14870503793991.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037950512.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037968313.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037982314.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037997515.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705038013416.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="lightbox">
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
  <div class="left">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
</div>

</div>
```

**Note:** Please Run Code Snippet In Full screen

Comment: You Can Use Free Plugin Like This:
[Free Lightbox Plugin](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: Thank You For Helping Me But What I Need Is Create Lightbox Slide From Scratch

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this.

I only added a few lines to your `js`

**UPDATE**: added previous button and fade effect.

**UPDATE 2**: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leon_Klaj/7mphfvk2/) with some ideas that can help you to develop your slideshow.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        var first_img = $(".image img:first");

        var last_img = $(".image img:last");

        $(".lightbox img").attr("src", first_img.attr('src'));

        $(".image img").click(function (e) {

            $(".lightbox img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        });


      $(".lightbox .next").click(function (e) {

            var img = $('.image img[src="' + $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src') + '"]').parent().next('div').find('img');

            if (img.length === 0) { img = first_img; }

            $(".lightbox img").attr("src", img.attr('src')).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn(200);


        });

        $(".lightbox .prev").click(function (e) {

            var img = $('.image img[src="' + $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src') + '"]').parent().prev('div').find('img');

            if (img.length === 0) { img = last_img; }

            $(".lightbox img").attr("src", img.attr('src')).stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn(200);


        });

    });
```

```css
.image{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
.image img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
.lightbox{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px auto;
    border:2px solid #0094ff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 234, 119, 0.80);
}
.lightbox img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.lightbox .next{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 234, 119, 0.80);
    cursor:pointer;
}
.lightbox .prev{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 234, 119, 0.80);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/14870503793991.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037950512.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037968313.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037982314.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037997515.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705038013416.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="lightbox">
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
   <div class="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Leaon Klaj, Please I Will Update The Code To Add previous Button So Could You Help Me With The Previous Button And Fade Effect :)

Comment: @MichaelNeas, i have updated the code to add the previous and fade effect.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Could You Please Explain Me The Code In The Next Click function.

Comment: $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src') gives me the src of the image in the lightbox. With that information, i get the next image of the div.image that is after the div with the image in the lightbox.

Comment: Thank You, $(this) is Return with Body element So What $(this) mean is it mean .lightbox .next or .image img.

Comment: And Another Question you Write Function Find("img") so Which is Img, I Can Understand The Logic Of Idea But I'd Like To Understand The Code

Comment: $(this) = div.next. So i get it´s parent (=.lightbox) then the img inside. For  more information: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 2):

Try this, make an array of images while clicking on it, and then show them on `.next` click.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [];
    var j;
    $(".image img").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        j = $(this).attr("src");
        $(".lightbox img").attr("src", j);
        images.push(j);
    });
    var i = 0;
    $(".lightbox .next").click(function (e) {
        $(".lightbox img").attr("src", images[i]);
        i++
    });
})
```

```css
.image{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
.image img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
.lightbox{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px auto;
    border:2px solid #0094ff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:40px;
}
.lightbox img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.lightbox .next{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 234, 119, 0.80);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/14870503793991.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037950512.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037968313.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037982314.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705037997515.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-02/148705038013416.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="lightbox">
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much, Please I Will Update The Code To Add previous Button So Could You Help Me With The Previous Button And Fade Effect :), I'd Like To Understand More And More About Javascript, Thank You Again

Comment: Thank You for Helping Me But I Checked Your Code But it is not work Why?

Comment: Above Snippet is working quite well, check for errors in console, and for previous button, just add another function with `-` loop.

Comment: I Run The Code Snippet In Stackoverflow and It's Not Work, Thank You

Comment: The Next Button not Work Try It Please